# Strongly type PS custom object properties

Tags: powershell, object, properties, typing

I have been using hash tables to return complex data from functions, and it has worked well, but I would like to have the keys strongly typed, since I have booleans, strings, arrays of strings, ordered dictionaries and such in the returned hash tables. So, given something like this

```
[hashtable]$hashtable = @{
    one = 1
    two = "two"
}
```

I have the issue that the type of each key is weakly typed. I want to basically do this

```
[hashtable]$hashtable = @{
    [int]one = 1
    [string]two = "two"
}
```

But that's not valid code. So I thought I could do this

```
[psCustomObject]$object = [psCustomObject]@{
    [int]one = 1
    [string]two = "two"
}
```

But that's invalid too. I find this a bit ugly, and it also doesn't work

```
$object = New-Object -typeName:PSObject
$object | Add-Member -memberType:int -name:'one' -value:1
$object | Add-Member -memberType:string -name:'two' -value:'two'
```

So, am I SOL and there is no way, or no elegant way, to create a custom object with strongly typed properties?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8), where you can set each column to contain a certain DataType?

Comment: @Theo, I am not familiar with data tables, but given that my end goal is not formatting for output I am thinking that's not the solution. I want to able to have a function return a complex data structure, and I want to be able to strongly type the return object so that I catch any errors where I assign the wrong data type to a property in the function. Often the resulting data will never be used for anything other than a conditional in the calling code.

Comment: A DataTable is not for formatting output, but instead a structure to store data, just like a PSObject. The main difference is that with a DataTable, you define strongly typed data types on each 'field' (column) so it will not accept any other data type. There are plenty of examples of how to use it, like [here](https://www.petri.com/dancing-on-the-table-with-powershell) for instance. Sounds to me that is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Theo; I see now. It does look like I could do what I want, but at the expense of a much more convoluted initialization, as well as data referencing. I am starting to wonder if maybe the reason you can't do this easily with hash tables or PSCustomObject is because most people don't think there is a need to. Which makes me wonder if I am either structuring my functions badly or just worrying too much.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the hashtable literal you'll want to type-cast the *value expression* instead:

```
PS C:\> $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    one = [int]1
    two = [string]"two"
}
PS C:\> $object|gm -MemberType NoteProperty

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name MemberType   Definition
---- ----------   ----------
one  NoteProperty int one=1
two  NoteProperty string two=two
```

This will, however, not prevent anyone from storing a non-integer or non-string in any of the properties - psobject property are simply not strongly typed.

---

If you want type safety for properties you'll need to create a [new type with the `class` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes):

```
class MyOneTwo
{
    [int]$One
    [string]$Two

    MyOneTwo(){}

    MyOneTwo([int]$one, [string]$two){
        $this.One = $one
        $this.Two = $two
    }
}

# Create instances with ::new(), New-Object or a cast:
$object = [MyOneTwo]::new(1,"2")
$object = New-Object MyOneTwo -Property @{ One = 1; Two = "2" }
$object = [MyOneTwo]@{ One = 1; Two = "2" }
```

Comment: that will set the type, but not strongly. I could always come back later and assign a string to the first property like $object.one = [string]'one'

Comment: @Gordon That would be the same if you used `Add-Member -TypeName` - psobject properties are simply not strongly typed - for that you'll need [a class definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes)